# Class Template Issues

Tags: c++, class, templates

so I'm working with a linked list and I've got all the functions to work when they are working with ints. I've started adjusting the program to follow a template so that it can work with other given data types such as double but this has broken the entire program and I'm not sure why so if you know why it's causing this and how to resolve it that would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "List.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   List<int> linkedList;
   linkedList.insertByPos(0,16);
   linkedList.insertByPos(1,17);
   linkedList.insertByPos(2,18);
   linkedList.printList();

   linkedList.reverse();
   cout << endl;
   linkedList.printList();

   cout << "The position is " << linkedList.search(17) << endl;
   linkedList.insertByPos(3,19);
   linkedList.printList();
   linkedList.RemoveByPos(2);
   cout << endl;
   linkedList.printList();
    return 0;
}
```

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H
template <class T>
class List
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        T data;
        Node* next;
    };
    Node* head;
    Node* curr;
    Node* temp;
public:
    List<T>();
    List(const List<T>& other);
    void printList();
    void reverse();
    int search(T value);
    void insertByPos(int pos, T value);
    void RemoveByPos(int pos);

};

#endif // LIST_H
```

```
#include "List.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
List<T>::List()
{
    head = nullptr;
    curr = nullptr;
    temp = nullptr;
}
template <class T>
List<T>::List(const List& other)
{
    cout << "copy constructor called:\n";
    if(other.head == nullptr) return;
    Node* dummyHead = new Node;
    curr = dummyHead;
    Node* othcurr = other.head;
    for(; othcurr!=nullptr; othcurr = othcurr->next)
    {
        curr->next = new Node;
        curr = curr->next;
        curr->data = othcurr->data;
        curr->next = nullptr;
    }
    head = dummyHead->next;
    delete dummyHead;
}
template <class T>
void List<T>::printList()
{
    curr = head;
    while(curr != nullptr)
    {
        cout << curr->data << endl;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}
template <class T>
void List<T>::reverse()
{
    Node* next = nullptr;
     curr = head;
    while(curr != nullptr)
    {
        next = curr->next;
        curr->next = temp;
        temp = curr;
        curr = next;
    }
    head = temp;
    temp = nullptr;
}
template <class T>
int List<T>::search(T value)
{
    int counter = 0;
    curr = head;
    while(curr != nullptr && curr->data != value)
    {
        curr = curr->next;
        counter++;
    }
    if(curr == nullptr)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    return counter;
}
template <class T>
void List<T>::insertByPos(int pos, T value)
{
    curr = head;
    Node* n = new Node;
    n->data = value;
    int counter = 0;
    int bounds = 0;
    while(curr != nullptr)
    {
        bounds++;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    if(bounds <= pos)
    {
       pos = bounds;
    }
    curr = head;
    while(counter != pos)
        {
            counter++;
            temp = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        n->next = curr;
                if(counter == 0)
                {
                    head = n;
                }
                else
                {
                    temp->next = n;
                }
    temp = nullptr;
}
template <class T>
void List<T>::RemoveByPos(int pos)
{
   Node* delPtr = nullptr;
   curr = head;
   temp = head;
   int counter = 0;
   int bounds;
     while(curr != nullptr)
    {
        bounds++;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    if(pos >= bounds)
    {
        cout << "Bad pos value";
    }
    else
        {
                curr = head;
   while(counter != pos)
   {
       counter++;
       temp = curr;
       curr = curr->next;
   }
   delPtr = curr;
   curr = curr->next;
   temp->next = curr;
      if(counter == 0)
   {
       head = head->next;
       temp = nullptr;
   }


   delete delPtr;
        }

}
```

Comment: What kind of errors do you get? Does it not compile? If so, please add the compiler error message. Or does it compile but crashes at runtime? If so, please add whatever diagnostics you get. Please also add code to show how you use your list.

Comment: I'm getting missing template arguments before 'linkedList'| and  'linkedList' was not declared in this scope

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "T" after "List"

```
List::List() void -> List<T>::List()

void List::printList() -> void List<T>::printList()
```

Comment: I've added this to all of the functions and now I'm receiving an error when I declare my object in main which says it was not declared in this scope.

Answer (score 0):

There multiple problems with due to the templates. First when you instiantiate linkedList you must tell the compiler which type T should have. For example by writting

```cpp
List<int> linkedList;
```

For the same reason you must change

```cpp
List<T>::List(const List& other)
// to 
List<T>::List(const List<T>& other)
```

Furthermore, you cannot (easily, there are some ways) put the definitions of templated functions in the cpp file. You have to put them in the header file. For more read 
https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#templates-defn-vs-decl Your code would throw a linker error after you got it to compile otherwise.

Comment: When I specify my LinkedList object its no longer recognizing any of the functions I declared do you know why that is?

Comment: I copied your code from above, put the List.cpp in the List.hpp following the declaration of the List and changed two lines and it worked:
(in the declaration):
List<T>(); -> List();
(in the definition):
List<T>::List(const List& other) -> List<T>::List(const List<T>& other)